# Replace line with new line and return

Tags: php, replace

I have this line in a text file on my server:

```
*/
$config['default_theme'] = 'seaside';

/*
```

I want to replace it with:

```
*/
$config['default_theme'] = 'river';

/*
```

'river' is stored in a variable $themename.
I can search this file and replace the line, but want to include the carriage return, eg the /n
My current code does not do this and I lose the space below the line.

Here is my current php code:

```
if (stristr($line,'default_theme')) {
    $line = '$config[\'default_theme\'] = ' . '\'' . $themename . '\';' ;
```

How can I integrate this \n or better rewrite it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just wanting to do this:

```
if (stristr($line,'default_theme')) {
    $line = '$config[\'default_theme\'] = ' . '\'' . $themename . '\';'."\n" ;
```

PHP will expand the `"\n"` into a carriage return and your new line will now be:

```
"$config['default_theme'] = 'river';
"
```

*(note the "invisible" new line)*

PHP will not expand special characters if they are quoted with single quotes (e.g. \t \n \r) but if using double quotes they will be replaced.

---

One extra (mildly related note), is that you could simplfy your line by using `"`'s instead of `'`'s; removing the need for escaping:

```
$line = "$config['default_theme'] = '" . $themename . "'\n";
```

This is because you can use both `'`'s and `"`'s to encapsulate strings in PHP, as your string contains `'`'s i'd advise using `"`'s because this means you don't need to escape it's contents!

You could even drop it down to the following, as php searches string's for variables and will expand them.

```
$line = "$config['default_theme'] = '$themename'\n";
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, couldn't see that and tried lots of combinations but didn't do the speech marks!

Comment: Accepted. Couldn't accept your answer immediately, there is a timer preventing it. Thanks again Pez